# bash: how to extract thousands of non-sequential lines from a file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, extract, lines

I have a file with millions of lines. I also have a list of line numbers, a few hundred thousand which are non-sequential and without a pattern. I would like to extract the lines of the file with the list of line numbers. How can I achieve this efficiently in linux?

Comment: By `efficient` do you mean less of your time or less of the computer's time?

Comment: Step 1 sort the line numbers in ascending order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the list of linenumbers in a file then with `awk` you can do something like this -

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1];next } (FNR in a)' line_number_list.txt bigfile.txt
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat bigfile.txt
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10

$ cat line_number_list.txt
1
2
4
5
8
9

$ awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1];next } (FNR in a)' line_number_list.txt bigfile.txt
line1
line2
line4
line5
line8
line9
```